# How to make sure, that I have operated with every pair of elements in std::set in loop with insertion?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, set

```
std::set<BooleanFunction>::iterator  it;
for(it=closure.begin (); it!=closure.end (); ++it)
{ 

  std::set<BooleanFunction>::iterator  jit;
  for(jit=closure.begin (); jit!=closure.end (); ++jit)
  {

    for(uint i=0U; i<it->Arity (); ++i)
    { BooleanFunction  f = it->Superposition (*jit, i);

      if( f.Arity () <= test.Arity () )
       closure.insert (f);
    }
  }
}
```

How can I make sure, that every two elements have the Superposition with each other?

Edit: Self superposition also possible: f(f(x)), f(f(f(x))), ... - is OK.

Comment: You are inserting items into the set while iterating on it. Is that by design?

Comment: @RSahu Yes, it is. I can get the items to insert only iterating (construct new one using two others). My working version of this program is using the vector, the order in it (push_back ()) and every internal loop iteration it must to call the find to insert only unique element. I want to make the optimization and to use a set for it? Is it possible?

Comment: @so-olitary - And you were able to accomplish this with vector without the iterators becoming invalid?

Comment: There is a possibility that you will insert an item before the iterator and fail to check for superposition.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, adding an item to a set or vector doesn't invalidate existing iterators.

Comment: @RSahu 'or vector' is wrong

Comment: @DieterLücking, yes, of course.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I was wondered to know, that iterators become invalid after push_back, but I handle this problem: I just used indexes for(uint i=0; i<size; ++i)...  )))

Comment: If someone interested in, how I used std::vector for it. I can publish my code somewhere.

Comment: @so-olitary the set is ordered, and the iterator follows tis order.  If the element you insert is smaler than current element, you have to process it (extra loop-gymnastic) otherwhise you can just go on.

Comment: I would think you need 2 sets.  The one you are going through and a  set to build into.  iterate through the original set and add things to the set you need to build while you are doing that.

Comment: @NathanOliver, so I need to repeat the whole search for the unite of these sets and get new one. Then repeat for these sets... It is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think you could use 2 sets like the following.

```
std::set<BooleanFunction> builder
std::set<BooleanFunction>::iterator  it;
for(it=closure.begin (); it!=closure.end (); ++it)
{ 
    bulider.insert(*it);
    for(uint i=0U; i<it->Arity (); ++i)
    {
        BooleanFunction  f = it->Superposition (*it, i);
        if( f.Arity () <= test.Arity () )
            builder.insert (f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extra loop-gymnastic looks very scary:

```
void  smart_insert (std::set<BooleanFunction>  &closure,
                    std::set<BooleanFunction>::iterator  it,
                    std::set<BooleanFunction>::iterator jit,
                       const BooleanFunction   &f, uint arity)
{
  if( f.Arity () <= arity && closure.find (f) == closure.end () )
  { 
    if( f < *jit )
    { std::set<BooleanFunction>::iterator  nit;
      ++it;

      for(nit=closure.begin (); nit!=it; ++nit)
       for(uint i=0U; i<nit->Arity (); ++i)
       { BooleanFunction  ff = nit->Superposition (f, i);

         smart_insert (closure, nit, closure.find (f), ff, arity);
       } // end for i
    } // end if *jit
    if( f < *it )
    { std::set<BooleanFunction>::iterator  njit;
      ++jit;

      for(njit=closure.begin (); njit!=jit; ++njit)
       for(uint i=0U; i<f.Arity (); ++i)
       { BooleanFunction  ff = f.Superposition (*njit, i);

         smart_insert (closure, closure.find (f), njit, ff, arity);
       } // end for i
    } // end if *it
    closure.insert (f);
  } // end if arity & unique
}

// ...
std::set<BooleanFunction>::iterator  it;
for(it=closure.begin (); it!=closure.end (); ++it)
{ 

  std::set<BooleanFunction>::iterator  jit;
  for(jit=closure.begin (); jit!=closure.end (); ++jit)
  {

    for(uint i=0U; i<it->Arity (); ++i)
    { BooleanFunction  f = it->Superposition (*jit, i);

      smart_insert (closure, it, jit, f, test.Arity () );
    }
  }
}
```